# R - Counting rows until match is achieved by group

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with a dataset of lat/lons where I'm trying to figure out how many "segments" of a trip have elapsed before a driver returns to his/her original location. Each row of my data frame corresponds to a a pair of starting and ending coordinates. If, for example, the driver travels from home - work and then work - home, it took them 1 segment to return home. If, however, the driver travels from home - work - a bar - home, it took them 2 segments to return home (work - a bar and then bar - home). I have a dataset with many individuals and I want to be sure that the counting occurs within individual only.

Here is a simple toy dataset:

```
    df <- data.frame("ID" = c(rep("individual1", 6), rep("individual2", 3)),
                "trip_start_lat" = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2),
                "trip_start_lon" = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2, 3),
                "trip_end_lat" = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4),
                "trip_end_lon" = c(2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 3, 5))
```

It seems to me like there should be a solution with data.table (and ideally I would use data.table for this as my real dataset is like a million rows), but I'm struggling to come up with one. My desired output would be:

```
    df <- data.frame("ID" = c(rep("individual1", 6), rep("individual2", 3)),
                "trip_start_lat" = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2),
                "trip_start_lon" = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2, 3),
                "trip_end_lat" = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4),
                "trip_end_lon" = c(2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 3, 5),
                "desired_output" = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2))
```

The desired_output column shows NA in the first row because the individual drove from a destination they won't return to (this is typical for the dataset. Individuals are often installing their data loggers at an uncommon site for their driving routines), NA in the second row because the individual departed from a location they haven't yet returned to, and then 1 in the third row because it took 1 segment to return to the previous destination. NAs in the fourth and fifth row because the driver hasn't yet returned to their home destination (1, 2) a second time. Then 2 in row 6 because the driver returns after driving 2 additional segments. Row 7 is NA because it is a new ID.

Comment: Why does row 9 get `2`? The destination is unique.

Comment: This seems a bit more like a network graph, connecting each segment and determining where cycles exist. I suggest you go down that direction, perhaps using the `igraph` package (I don't have an immediate suggestion for how to proceed). The wording of your requirements may need tweaking, since you say "original location" but found a match in the second row of the first few rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is more of an algorithm problem, not a programming problem. It might be seen as off-topic by some users, good luck with getting a solution!

Comment: Sorry @r2evans. I fixed the issue with row 9. That was a mistake.

Comment: Is it necessary to assume that rows are ordered chronologically, and that the order of rows is critical?

Comment: Oh. Excellent point. Yes. I have already ordered the rows by ID, date, and departure time but maintaining that order is important.

Comment: shouldn't row 9 have a `1` instead of a `2`, since it departs from that individuals first row?

Comment: The row 9 desired output is a 2 because individual2 travels from 4,5 - 2, 2 - 2, 3 - 4, 5. So it is two segments (akin to the home - work - bar - home example in the top of the post)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, it's all relative to different trips per individual. For instance, individual 1's first three rows and second three rows are distinct (or even more groups than two), which means that they need to be either grouped better or auto-infer which is in which group. This seems very much cycle-finding in graph theory.